# Dom Xpath issue

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, xpath

I don't get why I can't get nothing with XPath. What's wrong?

```
<?php
$dom_object = new DOMDocument();
$domxpath_object = new DOMXpath($dom_object);

$dom_object->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><databases><foo>bar</foo></databases>');
$domnodelist_object = $domxpath_object->query('/');
echo '<pre>' . print_r($domnodelist_object->item(0)->hasChildNodes(), true) . '</pre>'; // output: nothing

print_r($dom_object->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue); // output bar
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can't recall if the xpath updates, have you tried putting the `new DOMXPath()` after the `->loadXML()`?

Comment: @Orbling - could you post your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki: As requested, now an answer.  Because the previous comment was not targetted at me, I did not notice it had become an accepted answer.  Thank you for the notification.

Answer (score 1):

*[Comment converted to answer, for the benefit of those searching here after.]*

`DOMXpath` seems to establish it's state at the time of creation rather than linking to the `DOMDocument` it was created from.  Updates to the `DOMDocument`, in this case a `->loadXML()` call do not follow through to the `DOMXpath` object.

It is therefore necessary to load the XML, create the full DOM tree, before instantiating the XPath object.

```
<?php
$dom_object = new DOMDocument();    
$dom_object->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><databases><foo>bar</foo></databases>');

// XPath created from DOMDocument, after loading
$domxpath_object = new DOMXpath($dom_object);

$domnodelist_object = $domxpath_object->query('/');

// ... additional processing
```